# How is CipherTrace tracking monero transactions and what tools are they using?

Tags: privacy

On August 31, 2020. Ciphertrace released: https://ciphertrace.com/ciphertrace-announces-worlds-first-monero-tracing-capabilities/

What are these tracing tools doing exactly to trace monero?

> CipherTrace delivers Monero tracing tools to the U.S. Department of
> Homeland Security to support investigations of crimes. Menlo Park, CA
> – August 31 2020 – Leading cryptocurrency intelligence company
> CipherTrace has developed tools for the U.S. Department of Homeland
> Security (DHS) to track transactions of notoriously difficult-to-trace
> privacy coin Monero (XMR).
>
> CipherTrace’s contract with DHS Science & Technology Directorate
> resulted in the development of forensic tools for law enforcement and
> government agencies to trace and visualize Monero transaction flows
> for criminal investigations. CipherTrace developed tools to explore
> Monero transactions to assist in investigations. These tools include
> transaction search, exploration, and visualization tools for Monero
> transaction flows that have been integrated with CipherTrace’s
> Inspector financial investigations product. This provides ways to
> track stolen Monero currencies or Monero currencies used in illegal
> transactions. It also helps assure cryptocurrency exchanges, OTC
> trading desks, investment funds and custody providers that they do not
> accept Monero from illicit sources and investigate Monero received
> from potentially illicit sources and take appropriate actions to stay
> in compliance.
>
> With 45% of darknet markets now using Monero—the second-favorite
> cryptocurrency of choice among criminals just behind bitcoin—law
> enforcement interest in Monero tracing has soared. Monero employs a
> particularly unique design to ensure user anonymity including
> always-on, enforced privacy. Ring signatures, which enable transaction
> mixing, are built into the protocol design, so when attempting to
> locate the source of a transaction, it will appear as if a whole crowd
> of users took part in the exchange, making it nearly impossible to
> identify the true source.
>
> “Monero (XMR) is one of the most privacy-oriented cryptocurrencies,”
> said Dave Jevans, CEO of CipherTrace. “Our research and development
> team worked for a year on developing techniques for providing
> financial investigators with analysis tools. There is much work still
> to be done, but CipherTrace is proud to announce the world’s first
> Monero tracing capability. We are grateful for the support of the
> Department of Homeland Security’s Science & Technology Directorate on
> this project.”
>
> The tools CipherTrace developed within the scope of this DHS project
> have also laid the groundwork for future implementation of entity
> transactions clustering, wallet identification, exchange attribution,
> and other functionality that will provide law enforcement with even
> more tools for investigating Monero transactions and addresses.
>
> For media inquiries, please contact Kili Wall at (310) 260-7901 or
> Kili(at)MelrosePR(dot)com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Press Release (which is all it is) has already been discussed at length on Reddit and largely refuted. The CEO even admitted in an [interview](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/ik9uhc/ciphertraces_monero_tracing_tool_chat_with_dave/) they are just using *heuristics* (he also showed not knowing the difference between a wallet address and an output public key so take from that what you will as to the authenticity/credibility of the rest of their claims).